# How to calculate alpha and beta parameters from an known mean and variance in normal-inverse gamma distribution

Tags: distributions, bayesian, inverse-gamma-distribution

How can I calculate the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameters for a normal-inverse gamma distribution if I know the mean and variance?

Comment: What's the parameterization you're using?

Comment: What is missing from the [dedicated Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-inverse-gamma_distribution)?

Comment: @Glen_b shape and rate